# Using Linq to select property using an expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object like this:

```
public class Sheet
{
    public decimal? Value1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a linq query that builds a list of `Tuple<int, Sheet>`.  The int is a percentage value stored in our database.  This could be a wrapper class, but for simplicity I am using a Tuple.

Then I have an extension method

```
public static decimal CalculateValue(this List<Tuple<int, Sheet>> sheets, Expression<Func<Tuple<int, Sheet>, decimal?>> field)
{
    //return sum of int / 100 * field
}
```

What I want to do is call something like this (list actually built from objects using linq)

```
List<Tuple<int, Sheet>> sheets = new List<Tuple<int, Sheet>>();

var value1 = sheets.CalculateValue(x => x.Value1);
var value2 = sheets.CalculateValue(x => x.Value2);
```

I do not want to use reflection.  I do not want "magic" strings for the properties `Value1` or `Value2`.  Is there a way for my extension method to grab the property using the expression and then multiply it by the percentage, and then sum the result across the collection?

Comment: Why you are using expression instead of simple Func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to API which you are trying to build, you should pass property selector for `Sheet` object, not for `Tuple<int, Sheet>`. You also can use simple `Func` delegate instead of expression, because you are working with in-memory objects.

It's not clear how you are going to handle null values - it definitely makes no sense to multiply by null, so I just use zero instead of null (such values will not affect sum):

```
public static decimal CalculateValue(
    this List<Tuple<int, Sheet>> sheets, Func<Sheet, decimal?> field)
{
    return sheets.Sum(t => t.Item1 * field(t.Item2).GetValueOrDefault() / 100);
}
```

Keep in mind - when you apply division operator on two integers, [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is used. If `Item1` value is less than `100`, this division will produce `0` as result. That's why I put multiplication operator first.